# ¿Por qué no puedo hacer Http PUT en Angular?

Tags: angular, http

Estoy tratando de hacer una petición PUT para modificar algo en mi base de datos MongoDB

```
   cambiar_pedido()
  {
    return this._http.put('http://localhost:4201/api/cambiar_pedido/7367208585/1232',{})
  }
```

Como ejemplo intenté utilizar esta función para realizar el respectivo cambio, sin embargo, aunque utilizando EXACTAMENTE la misma URL en POSTMAN, me funciona de maravilla... En el código real deja de funcionar, estoy utilizando MEAN STACK.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Solo faltaba hacerle el observable con su respectivo subscribe!]

Solo faltaba hacerle el observable con su respectivo subscribe! Wow!